# Add more white color to Gimp layer

Tags: color, gimp

How can I add more white color to a Gimp layer?

What about adding other colors to it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was searching for *Color balance*.

1. Select the layer
2. Click *Tools* -> *Color Tools* -> *Color Balance*
3. A new window will be opened:

> [image]

Here you can modify the colors. If you need more *white*, uncheck the *Preserve luminosity* checkbox and move all the sliders to right.